# Sharing delegation methods between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry, delegation

Model A and Model B share the following delegation methods:

```
  delegate :league, :to => :event, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => false # event_league

  def event_league_sport
    self.event_league.sport
  end

  def event_league_sport_name
    event_league_sport.name
  end
```

So that I don't have to repeat the same methods in each class, what's the best way to share them between the two in a nice DRY way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the methods to a module and include said module in your classes:

```
module EventDelegator
  def event_league_sport
    self.event_league.sport
  end

  def event_league_sport_name
    event_league_sport.name
  end
end

class A
  include EventDelegator
end
```